# Empty multipart request with jersey 2, maven and tomcat 7

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, jersey, multipart

I have a problem with a project migration.
I used **Netbeans 7.4** to create a web application, using **Jersey 2**, **JSF 2** from the netbeans library and other home made library. 
Now, I moved to **Netbeans 8.1** with **maven** to manage the library dependencies. Both old and new web app use **Tomcat 7**

With the old source, my webservices using multipart works fine. With the new version, request seems to be empty.

Here is the code (it is the **SAME** code on old and new version, but the new code use maven now):

```
@POST
@Produces("application/pdf")
@Path("produce/{checksum}")
@RolesAllowed("admin")
public Response produce(@Context HttpServletRequest request, @PathParam("checksum") String checksum, @Context SecurityContext sc) {
    l.info(String.format("Produce request by user %s received at %s ", sc.getUserPrincipal().getName(), new Date()));

    try {
        File tempInputXml = File.createTempFile("input", ".xml");
        File tempZip = File.createTempFile("zip", ".zip");
        List<Part> parts = new ArrayList(request.getParts());
        l.info(String.format("%d parts", parts.size()));

        InputStream inputStream = null;
        if (parts.isEmpty()) {
            l.info("No part in the request, try other way");
            inputStream = request.getInputStream();
        } else {
            Part firstPart = parts.get(0);
            l.info(String.format("ContentType part 0: %s", firstPart.getContentType()));
            try (OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(tempZip)) {
                IOUtils.copy(firstPart.getInputStream(), os);
            }
        }
    ...
    byte[] pdfContent = ....;
    return Response.ok(pdfContent).build();
}
```

`request.getParts().isEmpty()` is always `true` with the new version whereas it was false with the older one.

Here is the pom.xml of the new version:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.lambdaj</groupId>
        <artifactId>lambdaj</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.36</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>  
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>  
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>  
        <version>3.5</version>  
    </dependency>  

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.11</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Here is the client code (and I can't change it at all sadly)

```
File temp = ...;
String md5 = md5Sum(temp);

String realUrl = "http://localhost:8080/soft/api/ws/produce/" + md5;
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(realUrl);

MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
builder.addBinaryBody("xml", temp);
HttpEntity multipart = builder.build();
httppost.setEntity(multipart);

HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

When I try to use `FormDataMultiPart` the client get a 415 HTTP error. With `@Context HttpServletRequest` with the old version, it was working fine

Where is my mistake?

Comment: What's with the jersey-multipart dependency if you are just going to read it from the servlet request? My guess is you registered the multipart feature which is reading the request prior to your reading it in the method. I imagine the servlet request does cache/buffer the data, so it can only be retrieved once. These are only assumptions, but maybe something to look into

Comment: Have never seen this way of consuming a Form Data request. I am used to handling it this way - `public Response produce(FormDataMultiPart multiPartData)` with `@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)`. (package for `FormDataMultiPart` class is ``com.sun.jersey.multipart` )

Comment: Have a look at the [Jersey documentation for multipart](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html#d0e9337). You might be better off using it's API rather than trying to extract the data from the servlet request

Comment: I just add the client code to my question

Comment: Register the `MultiPartFeature` with the Jersey app to use `FormDataMultiPart`

Comment: Thanks to you all, I registered the `MultiPartFeature` and now everything seems to be work just fine!